# Built-in functions and their common exceptions

Tags: python

I'm struggling with the Python [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/) in the topics related to exceptions and errors.

What I'm trying to find is what exceptions or errors can be thrown by the built-in functions in order to write the necessary validations to prevent them.

I'm not looking the list of exceptions y python, but the relation of this exceptions to the build-in functions.

Comment: here are the latest built in exceptions https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/exceptions.html

Comment: There is no list of all of the possible exceptions that could be thrown by each built-in function. Python doesn't have the idea of checked exceptions like Java does, they're all runtime.

Comment: Note that you should only try to catch exceptions that you actually can handle. It's bad practice to try to catch any exception unless you know that you can do something that's more contextually appropriate than whatever's up the stack from you is likely to do instead. (If the action would be "write an error to the user and exit", f/e, then that decision should be made _as close to the user as possible_ in the main function or similar, not done by a bunch of smaller individual exception handlers).

Comment: `except Exception` will catch everything inheriting from `Exception` (which is everything except a few exceptions used by the implementation that you almost certainly do *not* want to catch; it's not impossible to catch them as well, but I think it's worth ignoring them for now). In general, though, you *don't* want to catch everything, unless you plan on re-raising the exception. Catch the exceptions you *know* how to handle, and let the rest propagate.

Comment: Note that the exceptions you are worried about typically aren't meant to be handled: they are meant to be noticed during testing and *prevented*. `int` raised a `TypeError`? Go find out where you passed a blatantly incorrect value to `int` and stop doing that.